# how to join 10 table by using inner joins and group by condition

Tags: mysql

i want to convert this query into joins , this is a task which i got from my manger that Please convert the query below into Join format.

```
    SELECT 
                               capder.cder_id,
                               capman.cman_name AS Manufacturer,
                               caprange.cran_name AS Range1,
                               capmod.cmod_name AS Model,
                               capmod.cmod_code AS ModelCode,
                               capder.cder_doors AS Doors,
                               nvdbodystyle.bs_description AS BodyStyle,
                               captrim.ctrim_name AS Trim1,
                               capder.cder_name as Trim2, 
                               capder.cder_drivetrain AS DriveTrain,
                               nvdmodelyear.MY_ref AS DerivativeModelYear,
                                  group_concat(distinct(nvddictonaryoption.DO_Description) order by nvddictonaryoption.DO_Description SEPARATOR '|') AS ExteriorColour

                      FROM   capman,
                               caprange,
                               capmod,
                               nvdbodystyle,
                               capder,
                               nvdmodelyear,
                               captrim,
                               nvdoptions,
                               nvddictonaryoption,
                               nvddictionarycategory
                      WHERE  capman.cman_code = caprange.cran_mantextcode
                      AND    caprange.cran_code = capmod.cmod_rancode
                      AND    nvdbodystyle.bc_code = capmod.cmod_bodystyle
                      AND    capmod.cmod_code = capder.cder_modcode
                      AND    capder.cder_id = nvdmodelyear.my_id 
                      AND    captrim.ctrim_code = capder.cder_trimcode 
                      AND    nvdoptions.OPT_Id = capder.cder_id
                      AND    nvdoptions.opt_optioncode = nvddictonaryoption.DO_OptionCode
                      AND    nvddictionarycategory.dc_catcode = nvddictonaryoption.do_catcode
                      AND    nvddictionarycategory.dc_cth_type = 'C'
                      AND   SUBSTR(nvdmodelyear.MY_ref,1,4) > 2006
                      group by cder_id,SUBSTR(nvdmodelyear.MY_ref,1,4),captrim.ctrim_name
```

MySQL workbench 6.3 CE.
i tried this way

```
   SELECT 
                           cd.cder_id,
                           cm.cman_name AS Manufacturer,
                           cr.cran_name AS Range1,
                           cmd.cmod_name AS Model,
                           cmd.cmod_code AS ModelCode,
                           cd.cder_doors AS Doors,
                           nb.bs_description AS BodyStyle,
                           ct.ctrim_name AS Trim1,
                           cd.cder_name as Trim2, 
                           cd.cder_drivetrain AS DriveTrain,
                           nmy.MY_ref AS DerivativeModelYear,
                              group_concat(distinct(ndo.DO_Description) order by ndo.DO_Description SEPARATOR '|') AS ExteriorColour

                  FROM   capman cm
       inner join        caprange cr          on cm.cman_code = cr.cran_mantextcode
       inner join        capmod cmd           on cr.cran_code = cmd.cmod_rancode
       inner join        nvdbodystyle   nb    on nb.bc_code = cmd.cmod_bodystyle
       inner join        capder          cd   on cmd.cmod_code = cd.cder_modcode
       inner join        nvdmodelyear    nmy  on cd.cder_id = nmy.my_id 
       inner join        captrim          ct  on  ct.ctrim_code = cd.cder_trimcode 
       inner join        nvdoptions       nop   on nop.OPT_Id = cd.cder_id
       inner join        nvddictonaryoption ndo  on nop.opt_optioncode = ndo.DO_OptionCode
       inner join        nvddictionarycategory ndc on ndc.dc_catcode = ndo.do_catcode AND    ndc.dc_cth_type = 'C' AND   SUBSTR(nmy.MY_ref,1,4) > 2006
        group by cder_id,SUBSTR(nmy.MY_ref,1,4),ct.ctrim_name;
```

am i did correct? it is giving correct result but it is taking too long to execute and get results. is there any better way to execute this query only with joins syntax and i don't have access to put index to the table

Comment: First, note that your current query is invalid, because you are grouping by only three columns but then selecting a dozen other columns.  The query would not even run on most other databases.  Beyond this, if you want to make the query faster, you would need to look into indexing your tables.

Comment: [Use the Index, Luke !](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) is a great reading

Comment: @Cid is there any other way do it better way?

Comment: have you tried applying EXPLAIN on your query?  That way you can observe how your SQL performs.